# Multiple sound-recording programs with one sound-input on Kubuntu

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording

I am running Kubuntu on my desktop-pc.

I was running Teamspeak 3 and I had no sound-input problems.
But when I started Discord additionally, I was not able to talk in any way on it.

Later I found out that this has something to do with `alsa`, `pulseaudio` and the `input-channel-system`.

Here is my problem:
I really have no knowledge about audio and I found nothing that helped me in this situation (nothing what I had understand well enough to solve the problem). But I want to use multiple programs who need Audio input without limitation. How can I do this?

I am using Kubuntu for two days now, but I have used Ubuntu for about two years before that. On Ubuntu I had no such problem, it worked from the beginning.